# OpenVPN Routing between two networks

Tags: openvpn

I have two OpenVPN server instances running on a WRT54GL (Tomato f/w 1.27vpn), one uses 10.10.10.0/24 and has 3 of my virtual servers, with this being used to backup these servers nightly thru the vpn. I also connect to this instance via laptop when I'm out and about. This is working fine. Now to the problem.. I have the second OpenVPN instance configured on 10.10.11.0/24 and a virtual server connected there with a couple more to follow. I want to keep the networks separate since one is my personal stuff and the
others are for clients. Both OpenVPN instances are configured for client-to-client. My problem is when I'm out on the laptop, I get to the 10.10.10.0/24 subnet, since I get ifconfig-pushed a 10.10.10.0 addresss, but cannot figure out how/where to configure routing to allow me to get to/from the 10.10.11.0 network. I kind of expect that to be in the WRT54GL/Tomato routing table since that's the gateway for both networks, but I've tried all sorts of combinations and get no connection between the two networks.. 
It's gotta be simple, but I'm missing it...

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Tomato but with OpenVPN you can push more than more route to the clients with the following in your OpenVPN server config.

> push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0"
>   push "route 10.10.11.0 255.255.255.0"

But that said I'm not sure how much you'll be able to truly keep these networks separate with Tomato acting as the gatekeeper.  Without a proper firewall and either separate hardware or VLANs in place keeping these networks separate is going to be a loosing battle.  It's not that hard to add routes to your computer manually and gain access to this other network.  In fact I bet you could setup the route to this other network manually on your laptop and access it just fine through your existing OpenVPN setup.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can edit the openvpn.conf file on a WRT, but if you can; this is how to push a route to the client:

push "route 10.10.11.0 255.255.255.0"